# preg_match not working with variable made by strip_tags

Tags: php, regex

I've read a few possible duplicate questions, but I don't think they address this problem.

In the below test code, the 4th preg_match does not work. It does, however, work if you un-comment the third line and use the text which what I copied and pasted from the echo.

```
<?php
$html = file_get_contents('testhtml.txt');
$text = strip_tags($html);
//$text = 'body{font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;} a{color: #06c;} p{margin:0;} #message{width:600px;margin:0 auto;} .legal{margin-top:2em;} .footer{margin-top:1em;padding:5px;background:#999999;color:#fff;} .footer a{color:#fff;} .senderName,.label{font-weight:bold;} .link,.label,.hint{margin-top: 20px;} .header-separator{height:4px;background-color:#e4002b;width:100%;margin-top:17px;} tr,td{vertical-align:top;text-align:left;} img{border:0;} Property id: 416848282 Property address: 12/41 Fake Road, Town, Vic 3000 Property URL: http://myurl.comu User Details: Name: Warren Warren Email: warren@warren.com.au Phone: (03) 1234 7777 I would like to: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Comments: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla nec orci magna. Quisque facilisis aliquet massa eu feugiat. Mauris eleifend elit aliquet mi egestas, eu gravida augue tempus. Sed libero nunc, euismod non nisl nec, vehicula laoreet dolor. Suspendisse sed convallis diam, non porta arcu. Remember, you can only use the personal information contained in this email enquiry for the purposes of contacting the person about their property enquiry Contact Number: 9999999999 (8.00am - 7.00pm ESDST) Message sent from http://myurl.comu ';


echo $text . '<br /><br />';

$re = '/(?<=Name: )(.*?)(?= Email:)/s';
preg_match($re, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo '<br/>';

$re = '/(?<=Email: )(.*?)(?= Phone:)/s';
preg_match($re, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo '<br/>';

$re = '/(?<=Phone: )(.*?)(?= I would like to:)/s';
preg_match($re, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo '<br/>';

$re = '/(?<=I would like to: )(.*?)(?=Comments:)/s';
preg_match($re, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo '<br/>';

$re = '/(?<=Comments: )(.*?)(?= Remember, you can)/s';
preg_match($re, $text, $matches);
print_r($matches);
echo '<br/>';


?>
```

The contents of testhtml.txt is below. I'm wondering if the line breaks after "I would like to:" are causing problems, but I've also tried `preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text );` to clear it up first with no luck.

My question is: why is this not working and/or what is the difference between the two versions of $text?

```
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
body{font-family: arial,helvetica,sans-serif;}
a{color: #06c;}
p{margin:0;}
#message{width:600px;margin:0 auto;}
.legal{margin-top:2em;}
.footer{margin-top:1em;padding:5px;background:#999999;color:#fff;}
.footer a{color:#fff;}
.senderName,.label{font-weight:bold;}
.link,.label,.hint{margin-top: 20px;}
.header-separator{height:4px;background-color:#e4002b;width:100%;margin-top:17px;}
tr,td{vertical-align:top;text-align:left;}
img{border:0;}

</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id='message'>







    <BR/>
    <P>Property id: 416848282</P>
    <P>Property address: 12/41 Fake Road, Town, Vic 3000</P>
    <P>Property URL: <a href="http://myurl.com">http://myurl.comu</a></P>
    <BR/>
    <P>User Details:<P>
    <P>Name: Warren Warren</P>
    <P>Email: warren@warren.com.au</P>
    <P>Phone: (03) 1234 7777</P>
    <P>I would like to:
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.
    </P>
    <P>Comments: Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce aliquet purus ac ullamcorper condimentum. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Nulla nec orci magna. Quisque facilisis aliquet massa eu feugiat. Mauris eleifend elit aliquet mi egestas, eu gravida augue tempus. Sed libero nunc, euismod non nisl nec, vehicula laoreet dolor. Suspendisse sed convallis diam, non porta arcu. </P>

<div class="legal" style="color:#888;margin-top:140px;font-size:12px">
    <p>Remember, you can only use the personal information contained in this email enquiry for the purposes of contacting the person about their property enquiry</p>

    <br>
    <p>Contact Number: 9999999999 (8.00am - 7.00pm ESDST)</p>
</div>

    <div class="footer">
Message sent from <a href="http://myurl.com">http://myurl.comu</a>    </div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post an MVCE of the issue? String being tested and the lines needed to reproduce the issue. The `.` doesnt match new lines unless the `s` modifier is used. `$text` is a one liner so I think that could be the issue, unsure though without a clearer example..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that `strip_tags` still left me with a lot of line breaks even though these weren't shown when echoing. I found this by doing `echo "<pre>" . $text . '</pre>';`

Thus my solution to work the expressions given was to simply add `$text = preg_replace( "/\r|\n/", "", $text );` to remove all the line breaks.

Comment: So ignored comment?

Comment: Apparently, yes. Sorry I didn't see it. What is a MVCE?

Comment: It is the simplest version of your code to reproduce the issue, http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Try the `s` modifier and you shouldnt need the `preg_replace`.